# 2 Apache Websites on Different Ports

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd

I have a website(mysitedomain.com) which is running on http and https. Here is httpd.conf,

```
Listen 80
Listen 443
Listen 81

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mysitedomain.com
  DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName mysitedomain.com
  DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile C:/SSL/S-WildCard.cer
  SSLCertificateKeyFile C:/SSL/S-WildCard.key
  SSLCACertificateFile C:/SSL/S_chain_cert.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I wanna to run another website on mysitedomain.com:81, so I added,

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
  ServerName mysitedomain.com:81
  DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www2/"
</VirtualHost>
```

But this is not working. Anything I am missing?

Comment: is 81 port open? firewall?

Comment: Why would you want to do that when you can run multiple sites on the default ports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After confirming port is open, try removing the port in your vhost server name,  so it resembles:

```
    <VirtualHost *:81> 
        ServerName mysitedomain.com 
        DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www2/" 
    </VirtualHost>
```

You've already defined the port number to listen on. to access the domain being served out of your www2 directory, include the port number in the url

*mysitedomain.com:81*

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, if you cannot use separate host names or IP addresses (in my case caused by a dumb router), then the only variable left to define a VirtualHost is the port number. If there are two VirtualHosts on the same name and IP address then DefaultRuntimeDir must be set explicitly in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:

DefaultRuntimeDir /var/run/apache2

Working this way lets me use git branches and a post-update hook to manage feature branches during development of a small web site.